# Open CSV directly in IE imports to 1 column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, internet-explorer, csv

We are using a ASP MVC.
When displaying a report, we offer the user "Export to Excel" option.
If the user selects this option we call a query, returning a CSV result.

In Chrome and Firefox, the CSV file is saved to disk where the user can open the file and all works fine.

In IE, the user is presented with "What do you want to do with xxx.csv?"
-If they click "Open", the file opens, but all the csv data is in only the first column
-If they click "Save", the file is saved, where it can be opened with data appearing in separate columns.

Here is our C# code:

```
public ActionResult Csv()
{
   Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
   Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", @"filename=""TransactionHistory.csv""");

   return new FileStreamResult(service.RunReportAsCSV(), "text/csv");
}
```

UPDATE -------------------
This worked! :)

```
return File(service.RunReportAsCSV(), "text/csv", "TransactionHistory.csv");
```

Also removed to other Response calls.

Comment: Please show a few lines from the CSV file.  I suspect that there might be an issue with the formatting.

Comment: Have you tried with: `return File(service.RunReportAsCSV(), "text/csv", "TransactionHistory.csv");` and removing the .ContentType and .AddHeader() calls?

Comment: When you click "Open", in what application is the file opening? At a minimum, you should change the header to `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"TransactionHistory.csv\"`

Comment: Thank you thepirat000!  The CSV format seemed ok since, if you saved the file and then opened it, the columns were properly set.  The file was always being opened by MS Excel.

Comment: it worked by returning the File.